# Single design to support android tablets of different sizes and resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application which would support  android tablets of all sizes and resolutions. I went through the below [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

Even though it might be the best solution right now we have for designing based on different screen resolutions, issues will always be there. For example for **sw600dp**, **sw800dp** don't fit perfectly to screens having **sw720dp**. Even while designing based on density, the layout doesn't fit perfectly to the screen.So is there any other way to design for all types of tablet screens? do I have to design  multiple layouts  to fit into each of the screen resolutions available? Is there any way to design a single layout to fit into all tablet screen? need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is the  best way to designing  way to create beautiful  application ina adnroid .  linearlayout to same laout from other devices like phone ,tablet etc ..   " sdp "    dimen@_5sdp   all device to size is 5  .

Comment: @RajGohel sorry I couldn't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

you can just design pages based on percentage, there are android layout such as percentage relativelayout, percentage framelayout, linearlayout  support percentage design.

Comment: By the way will the texts will be properly resized?

Comment: no, but you can adjust text size ur self, take scaledDensity, widthPixels, heightPixels, from DisplayMetric, calculate the size u should use based on the percentage

Comment: percentage relativelayout is deprecated in android naugat. It says ConstraintLayout is the only solution left.